# Чтобы обновить OpenGL - нужно обновить драйвера видеокарты?

Tags: windows, opengl, драйвер

Я захотел обновить свой OpenGL 4.3 версии т.к. одна прога для 3D редактирования поддерживает только OpenGL 4.6 и выше.

На этом [сайте](https://technical.city/ru/video/GeForce-820M) характеристики моей видеокарты говорят что видеокарта
поддерживает OpenGL до версии 4.5.
[image: Характеристики видюхи]

Вот я пытаюсь обновить драйвера видеокарты чтобы получить самую последнюю и доступную мне версию OpenGL. Вроде как у меня последняя возможная обнова стоит.
[image: Пытаюсь обновить]

Программа OpenGL Extensions viewer же говорит что у меня на компе стоит OpenGL 4.3 версии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что OpenGL 4.6 мне все равно не получить с нынешней видеокартой, но просто интересно, почему у меня последние драйвера видеокарты установлены, OpenGL должен быть 4.5 версии, а у меня OpenGL 4.3. Непонятно.

Может, характеристики видеокарты на этом [сайте](https://technical.city/ru/video/GeForce-820M) неверные или я как-то не так обновляю OpenGL?

Я гуглил как обновить OpenGL и всё что выдаёт - туторы по тому как обновить драйвера видюхи. Я так понял, чтобы обновить OpenGL - нужно обновить драйвера видеокарты. Я прав?

Comment: OpenGL Extensions viewer на скриншоте показывает данные для встроенного адаптера intel

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаемая версия OpenGL это 2 компонента, как вы верно выяснили: видеокарта + драйвера.

Версия OpenGL, как таковая - это просто спецификация, список требований, того что аппаратно-программный комплекс должен уметь исполнять/выдавать. Если выдаёт - версия считается поддерживающейся.

Драйвера в этом вопросе "важнее". Если они "знают" про более новые версии спецификаций, то могут попытаться выжать их из "старой" видеокарты. Если же драйвера про "новый OpenGL" не в курсе, то точно ничего не получится. Как пример, некоторые драйвера могут вообще заявлять поддержку "любых" версий, и просто игнорировать команды на их использование, выводя только "голые" треугольники :-)

Итого - ищите более новые драйвера. В них могут добавить или расширить поддержку версий разными моделями видеокарт.

Comment: Я пробовал обновлять через Geforce Experiaence, он тоже говорит что у меня последние драйвера. Откуда брать ещё более новые драйвера если официальные источники твердят что новее драйверов для твоей видеокарты нет?